# CSV parsing from large logfile

Tags: shell, awk

I have a large comma separated logfile. I want to parse out some information.

```
 2010-02-10 10:00:00.000 171.606 bad_gateway
 2010-02-10 10:00:00.234 400.680 bad_gateway
 2010-02-10 10:00:00.410 212.308 login_from
 2010-02-10 10:00:00.601 222.251 bad_gateway
```

The problems are, i need to write out occurrences by a time range (example: between 10:00:00.000-11:00:00.000) and count how many was in a minute by duration length. I'm trying to do an output file like this:

```
 bad_gateway
 10:00
       AVG     <1ms     1-10ms   10-100ms  100-500ms     500+ms
       264.845                                     3

 login_from
 10:00
       AVG     <1ms     1-10ms   10-100ms  100-500ms     500+ms
       212.308                                     1

 bad_gateway                                
 10:01
       AVG     <1ms     1-10ms   10-100ms  100-500ms     500+ms
       xxx.xxx                                     x
```

Trying to figure out with awk, but stucked. Thanks for helping!

Here's what i got till now:

```
   BEGIN {
low["<1ms"]=0;high["<1ms"]=1
low["1-10ms"]=1;high["1-10ms"]=10
low["10-100ms"]=10;high["10-100ms"]=100
low["100-500ms"]=100;high["100-500ms"]=500
low[">500ms"]=500;high[">500ms"]=1000000000
 }
 {
    for (i in high) {
    if ((duration > low[i]) && (duration <= high[i]) ) {
    total+=duration
    bin[i]++
    count++
}
}
}
```

And in the END section, i do printf.

Comment: `I have a large comma separated logfile...` where are the commas?? or I forgot how does a comma look like.

Comment: My fault, i've made a clean file from the csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input data is short to test it thoroughly. Here you have an `awk` script that it does more or less what you are looking for. It's fully commented so from here you can modify it to suit to your needs:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    header = sprintf( "\t%-10s\t%10s\t%10s\t%10s\t%10s\t%10s", "AVG", "<1ms", "1-10ms", "10-100ms", "100-500ms", "500+ms" )

    ## Output slices if time.
    slices = "1 10 100 500"
    split( slices, slices_a )

    ## Hardcoded start and end times.
    start_time = mktime( "2010 02 10 10 00 00" )
    end_time = mktime( "2010 02 10 11 00 00" )
}

{
    ## Extract hour, minute and second from time.
    fields = split( $2, time, /[:.]/ )
    if ( fields != 4 ) { print "WARNING: Skipped line " FNR " because had bad formatted time." }

    ## Save previous time to be able to compare if a second has passed. First line is
    ## a special case because there is not yet a saved value.
    if ( FNR == 1 ) { 
        prev_time = mktime( "2010 02 10 " time[1] " " time[2] " " time[3] )
    }
    else { 
        curr_time = mktime( "2010 02 10 " time[1] " " time[2] " " time[3] )

        ## When a second has passed, print all extracted data.
        if ( curr_time - prev_time > 59 ) {

            print_minute_info(duration, prev_time, header, slices_a)

            ## Initialize data.
            prev_time = curr_time
            delete duration
        }
    }

    ## For each name (last field) concatenate durations.
    duration[ $NF ] = duration[ $NF] "|" $3
}

END {
    print_minute_info(duration, prev_time, header, slices_a)
}

## Traverse hash with following format (example):
## duration[ bad_gateway ] = "|34.567|234.918|56.213|"
##
## So, for each key split with pipe, sum its values and try to
## print a formatted output.
function print_minute_info(duration,prev_time,header,slices_a,       name,sum,times,times_a,num_times,i,times_avg,printed) {
    for ( name in duration ) {
        sum = 0
        times = substr( duration[name], 2 )
        split( times, times_a, /\|/ )
        num_times = length( times_a )
        for ( i = 1; i <= num_times; i++ ) {
            sum = sum + times_a[i]
        }
        times_avg = sum / num_times

        printf "%s\n", name
        printf "%s\n", strftime( "%H:%M", prev_time )
        printf "%s\n", header
        printf  "\t%-10s", times_avg

        ## This part tries to print the number of ocurrences just
        ## below its header. It can be improved.
        for ( i = 1; i <= length( slices_a ); i++ ) {
            if ( times_avg < slices_a[i] ) {
                printf "%10d\n", num_times
                printed = 1
                break
            }
            else {
                printf "\t%10s", ""
            }
        }
        if ( ! printed ) {
            printf "%10d\n", num_times
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

And assuming following `infile`:

```
2010-02-10 10:00:00.000 171.606 bad_gateway
2010-02-10 10:00:00.234 400.680 bad_gateway
2010-02-10 10:00:00.410 212.308 login_from
2010-02-10 10:00:00.601 223.251 bad_gateway
2010-02-10 10:01:00.401 224.251 bad_gateway
2010-02-10 10:01:00.701 225.251 bad_gateway
2010-02-10 10:01:04.401 226.251 login_to
2010-02-10 10:02:04.401 1.251 login_to
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

That yields:

```
login_from
10:00
    AVG               <1ms      1-10ms    10-100ms   100-500ms      500+ms
    212.308                                                1

bad_gateway
10:00
    AVG               <1ms      1-10ms    10-100ms   100-500ms      500+ms
    265.179                                                3

bad_gateway
10:01
    AVG               <1ms      1-10ms    10-100ms   100-500ms      500+ms
    224.751                                                2

login_to
10:01
    AVG               <1ms      1-10ms    10-100ms   100-500ms      500+ms
    226.251                                                1

login_to
10:02
    AVG               <1ms      1-10ms    10-100ms   100-500ms      500+ms
    1.251                          1
```

Comment: I got errors on running the script. In the line 56: illegal reference to local array times_a and line 70: illegal reference to local variable slices_a. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Telcom: I don't get any errors. I'm running it like: `awk -f script.awk infile` (added to the answer because had forgotten before) and also take into account the deliberate spaces in the function declaration. It's important in `awk` to distingish between parameters and local variables.

Comment: Me too, but gives me this two errors all the time. Trying to debug what's wrong, but without success till now.

Comment: @Telcom: I suspect it has something to do with the array parameters. Maybe `awk` thinks they are normal variables and complains when you try to execute an array function, like `length()` on them. Show us if you have an older version than mine, which is `GNU Awk 4.1.0`. I use a function to avoid to repeat that same code twice. If that problem is true, get rid of it without much problem.

Comment: @Birei Your style of writing and commenting scripts are sight for sore eyes. +1

Comment: @Jaypal: Thank you. It's nice to hear that :-)

Comment: @Birei: The gawk version was the problem, updated to 4.1.0 and hhe script working nice! Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proficient enough with awk but it is pretty easy in perl to do it... bin-ing data into buckets usually requires using hashes or array data structures.  Just regex extract the fields and then use a hash to create buckets that are counters, and increment the counter for each occurrence like so:

```
while( <> ) { # iterate over input file
   // extract fields here... e.g.
   //   $errType =~ /(\S+)$/;
   // etc.
   $bins->{$errType}{$time}{$duration}++;
}

# now iterate over hashes and print out your report
foreach $key1 ( keys %$bins ) {
    foreach ...
}
```

not quite the answer you were looking for, but maybe it gets you on the right track.